# Obtener valor de una función JavaScript en ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Tengo una función *javascript*

```
function prueba() {
var hotel = document.getElementById("titulo").innerHTML;
$('#MainContent_TextBox1').val(hotel);
```

}

Ahora quisiera recuperar ese valor en *aspx.cs*

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.UpdatePanel1, GetType(), "mifuncion", "prueba()", true);
        string[] separado = _url.Split('/');
        string final = separado[separado.Length - 1];
        Label1.Text = final;
        printDivs();
        //string a = titulo2.Value;
        string a = TextBox1.Text;
    }
```

Cuando debugeo, me dice que el texbox1 no tiene ningun texto, pero visualmente si lo tiene

Comment: when no hay respuestas :'(

Comment: Directamente como lo intentas hacer no es posible, pero lo que puedes hacer es enviar ese parámetro por medio de la URL

Comment: de la URL, de hecho inteté poner ese valor a un TEXTBOX, pero cuando quiere recuperar el valor del textbox, no está

Comment: Si te fijas, la variale `hotel` solo existe en ese momento para esa función de JavaScript. Sugiero que la asignes a un `HiddenField`, y ya luego ese sí lo puedes acceder en el CodeBehind

Comment: este es el hiddenfield <asp:HiddenField ID="titulo2" runat="server" /> y esta es la función function prueba() {
    var hotel = document.getElementById("titulo").innerHTML;
    $('#titulo2').val(hotel);
} asi debe ser?

Answer (score 3):

Acceder a una función de JavaScript a través del *CodeBehind* de C# no es posible, sugiero que declares un `HiddenField`, asignes el valor en la función de JavaScript y luego, ese `HiddenField` lo leas en el *CodeBehind*:

**Definición del `HiddenField`:**

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="titulo2" runat="server" />
```

**Asignación de un valor al `HiddenField` en la función de JavaScript:**

```
function prueba() {
    var hotel =  document.getElementById('<%= titulo2.ClientID %>');
    hotel.value = document.getElementById("titulo").innerHTML;
}
```

**Leer el contenido de la variable en el `CodeBehind`:**

```
var hotel = this.titulo2.Value;
```

Comment: en la linea de hotel.value es donde se lo debo de asignar al hiddden, no?, porque la variable "hotel" se debe de cargar con un "<p>" con id titulo

Comment: @Ernesto no comprendo exactamente, puedes poner un ejemplo?

Comment: si disculpa mira, la función es como, la de la pregunta, es igual,  var hotel = document.getElementById("titulo").innerHTML; esto es igual, pero el hidde lleva por id "titulo2"

Comment: @ErnestoEmmanuelYahLopez oh ya veo, listo, he actualizado mi respuesta asignando el valor a la variable `hotel` :D

Answer (score 0):

Por que no utilizas ajax.

```
 function sendDataAjax(nombre) {
            var actionData = "{'nombre': '" + nombre + "'
                               }";

            $.ajax(
            {
                url: "jqAjax.aspx/GetDataAjax",
                data: actionData,
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function(msg) { alert(msg.d); },
                error: function(result) {
                    alert("ERROR " + result.status + ' ' + result.statusText);
                }
            });        
        };
```

Comment: Pero con esto lo puedo recuperar en el codebehind de asp?